# How to implement a Named pipe using shared memory?

Tags: c, pipe, shared-memory, named-pipes

This is one of the toughest assignments that I've been given : I want (need) to implement
a named pipe (e.g. mkfifo functionality) using shared memory .

It took me some time , but finally I've succeeded to implement the `un-named pipe` , now I need to complete the Named , as mentioned above.

From my understanding the `Named pipe` uses `mkfifo` , meaning , creates a file on the disk , a then process `A` can read from the named pipe , and while reading , he blocks all other processes from writing into that file (aka named pipe) .... please correct me if I'm wrong !!?

Now , my question is how can I implement the named pipe with shared memory ?

With `un-named pipe` I open a shared memory segment , something like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define SHM_SIZE 1024  /* make it a 1K shared memory segment */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    key_t key;
    int shmid;
    char *data;
    int mode;

    if (argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: shmdemo [data_to_write]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* make the key: */
    if ((key = ftok("shmdemo.c", 'R')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* connect to (and possibly create) the segment: */
    if ((shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, 0644 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* attach to the segment to get a pointer to it: */
    data = shmat(shmid, (void *)0, 0);
    if (data == (char *)(-1)) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* read or modify the segment, based on the command line: */
    if (argc == 2) {
        printf("writing to segment: \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        strncpy(data, argv[1], SHM_SIZE);
    } else
        printf("segment contains: \"%s\"\n", data);

    /* detach from the segment: */
    if (shmdt(data) == -1) {
        perror("shmdt");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And each time one process wrote to it and another process read from it (and vice versa) .

Can you please explain the changes and/or functions that I'd to use ?

please note that I'm not allowed to use `open/close/read/write` system calls ...

Much appreciated

Comment: You just need an in-memory mapping between names (short strings, say, no more than 63 chars) and shared memory keys (of type key_t). You can base the mapping on some "master" shared memory segment with a known key. Put a container of pairs (char[64], key_t) there. Use a mutex to protect the region from simultaneous access. When creating a pipe, make a new key and add a (name, key) pair to the mapping; when opening an existing pipe, look up the name and use the corresponding key.

Comment: @n.m.: Friend ,this should be an answer .